# How to properly retrieve a record by ID

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my Angular/WebAPI app I'm struggling with retrieving a specific record by its id.
On the Front-End I have a controller and a data service. The controller calls a method on the data service, and the data service makes $http call to a WebAPI.
In my controller I'm passing the OID of the desired record to the getServiceRequestById method of the data service. Once of my issues is, that the actual value of that OID comes out as :1 instead of just 1.
My other issue is, that when the data service makes a call to WebAPI, the WebAPI perceives the request, as if it caries no ID in it, and passes that request onto its Get() method, instead of Get(int Id).
Here is my Front-End controller:

```
angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('EditServiceRequestCtrl',['$scope', 'requestsRepository','$routeParams',
    function ($scope, requestsRepository,$routeParams) {
        console.log("This is EditServiceRequestCtrl ; $routeParams:  " + $routeParams);
        //First we make a call to the data service, to fetch our ServiceRequest by its OID
        //Then, in the callback function, we populate the $scope models below with the data of our retreived ServiceRequest
        var getCleanId = function () {
            return $routeParams.OID.substring(0, 2)
        };
        var Id = getCleanId();
        //var cleanId = id.substring(0, 2);
        console.log('getCleanId  Id:   ' + Id);
        requestsRepository.getServiceRequestById(Id, function (request) {

            $scope.OID = request.OID;
            $scope.RequestorName = request.RequestorName;
            $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit = request.RequestorBusinessUnit;
            $scope.CustomerName = request.CustomerName;
            $scope.CscContactPerson = request.CscContactPerson;
            $scope.IsWbsCodeAvailable = request.IsWbsCodeAvailable;
            $scope.SalesforceIdNumber = request.SalesforceIdNumber;
            $scope.ProjectCtv = request.ProjectCtv;
            $scope.RequestedCompletionDate = request.RequestedCompletionDate;
            $scope.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration = request.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration;
            $scope.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove = request.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove;
            $scope.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh = request.toBeUsedForServerRefresh;
            $scope.DataRequirements = request.DataRequirements;
            $scope.DataProtectionRequirements = request.DataProtectionRequirements;
            $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability = request.ProjectedDataAvailability;
            $scope.DiscoveryLeadName = request.DiscoveryLeadName;
            $scope.SelectedCountries = request.SelectedCountries;
            $scope.ManualDiscovery = request.ManualDiscovery;
            $scope.AutomatedDiscovery = request.AutomatedDiscovery;
            $scope.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate = request.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate;
            $scope.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface = request.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface;
            $scope.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship = request.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship;

            $scope.countries = [
                {
                    name: "US", checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: "UK", checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: "France", checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: "Germany", checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: "Sweden", checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: "Danmark", checked: false
                }
            ];
            var list = [];

            $scope.checkit = function () {

                for (var p in $scope.countries) {
                    if ($scope.countries[p].checked) {
                        list.push($scope.countries[p].name);

                        console.log("selected country:  " + $scope.countries[p].name + "  " + $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability);
                    }
                } return list;
            }
            console.log('EditServiceRequestCtrl  $scope.RequestorName :   ' + $scope.RequestorName);
        });
    $scope.updateServiceRequest = function () {
        var ServiceRequest = {
            requestorName: $scope.RequestorName,
            requestorBusinessUnit: $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit,
            customerName: $scope.CustomerName,
            cscContactPerson: $scope.CscContactPerson,
            isWbsCodeAvailable: $scope.IsWbsCodeAvailable,
            salesforceIdNumber: $scope.SalesforceIdNumber,
            projectCtv: $scope.ProjectCtv,
            requestedCompletionDate: $scope.RequestedCompletionDate,
            projectedDataAvailability: $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability,
            toBeUsedForCloudMigration: $scope.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration,
            toBeUsedForDatacenterMove: $scope.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove,
            toBeUsedForServerRefresh: $scope.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh,
            dataRequirements: $scope.DataRequirements,
            dataProtectionRequirements: $scope.DataProtectionRequirements,
            selectedCountries:
                list.filter(function (itm, i, a) {
                    return i == a.indexOf(itm);
                }).toString(),
            projectedDataAvailability: $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability,
            discoveryLeadName: $scope.DiscoveryLeadName,
            manualDiscovery: $scope.ManualDiscovery,
            automatedDiscovery: $scope.AutomatedDiscovery,
            dataLoadUsingMasterTemplate: $scope.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate,
            dataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface: $scope.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface,
            dataLoaderRequiresSitizenship: $scope.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship

        };

        requestsRepository.updateServiceRequest(ServiceRequest);
    }
}]);
```

Here is my Front-End data service:

```
frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository',function ($http) {

    var createServiceRequest = function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests', method: "POST", data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("createServiceRequest Status: " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("createServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status + "  ServiceRequest:  " + ServiceRequest);
        });
    };

    var updateServiceRequest = function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests', method: "PUT", data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("updateServiceRequest Status: " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("updatetServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status + "  ServiceRequest:  " + ServiceRequest);
        });
    };

    var getServiceRequests = function (successCallback) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            successCallback(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return status;
        });
    };

    var getServiceRequestById = function (Id,successCallback) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests/' + Id

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("getServiceRequestById,  data:   " + data);
            successCallback(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return status;
        });
    };



    return {
        createServiceRequest: createServiceRequest, getServiceRequests: getServiceRequests,
        updateServiceRequest: updateServiceRequest, getServiceRequestById: getServiceRequestById
    };
});
```

And here is my Back-End WebAPI:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {

            var requestList = from req in new XPQuery<DummyRequest>(uow) select req;

            List<AccountViewServiceRequest> dataList = new List<AccountViewServiceRequest>();

            foreach(var item in requestList)
            {
                AccountViewServiceRequest sr = new AccountViewServiceRequest();
                sr.OID = item.Oid;
                sr.RequestorName = item.RequestorName;
                sr.RequestorBusinessUnit = item.RequestorBusinessUnit;
                sr.CustomerName = item.CustomerName;
                sr.CscContactPerson = item.CscContactPerson;
                sr.IsWbsCodeAvailable = item.IsWbsCodeAvailable;
                sr.SalesforceIdNumber = item.SalesforceIdNumber;
                sr.ProjectCtv = item.ProjectCtv;
                sr.RequestedCompletionDate = item.RequestedCompletionDate;
                sr.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration = item.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration;
                sr.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove = item.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove;
                sr.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh = item.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh;
                sr.DataRequirements = item.DataRequirements;
                sr.SelectedCountries = item.SelectedCountries;
                sr.DataProtectionRequirements = item.DataProtectionRequirements;
                sr.ProjectedDataAvailability = item.ProjectedDataAvailability;
                sr.DiscoveryLeadName = item.DiscoveryLeadName;
                sr.ManualDiscovery = item.ManualDiscovery;
                sr.AutomatedDiscovery = item.AutomatedDiscovery;
                sr.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate = item.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate;
                sr.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface = item.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface;
                sr.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship = item.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship;


                dataList.Add(sr);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataList.ToList()); 
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int Oid)
        {

            var item = (from req in new XPQuery<DummyRequest>(uow) where req.Oid == Convert.ToInt32(Oid) select req).First();

                AccountViewServiceRequest sr = new AccountViewServiceRequest();
                sr.OID = item.Oid;
                sr.RequestorName = item.RequestorName;
                sr.RequestorBusinessUnit = item.RequestorBusinessUnit;
                sr.CustomerName = item.CustomerName;
                sr.CscContactPerson = item.CscContactPerson;
                sr.IsWbsCodeAvailable = item.IsWbsCodeAvailable;
                sr.SalesforceIdNumber = item.SalesforceIdNumber;
                sr.ProjectCtv = item.ProjectCtv;
                sr.RequestedCompletionDate = item.RequestedCompletionDate;
                sr.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration = item.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration;
                sr.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove = item.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove;
                sr.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh = item.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh;
                sr.DataRequirements = item.DataRequirements;
                sr.SelectedCountries = item.SelectedCountries;
                sr.DataProtectionRequirements = item.DataProtectionRequirements;
                sr.ProjectedDataAvailability = item.ProjectedDataAvailability;
                sr.DiscoveryLeadName = item.DiscoveryLeadName;
                sr.ManualDiscovery = item.ManualDiscovery;
                sr.AutomatedDiscovery = item.AutomatedDiscovery;
                sr.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate = item.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate;
                sr.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface = item.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface;
                sr.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship = item.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship;


            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sr);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }
```

Which part should I correct to successfully retrieve a single e record based on its OID?

Comment: Not solution to your problem, but I think the use of `ngResource` may be more appropriate for your app.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint       if i understand correctly you are trying to use odata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that your first issue is related to this routine:

```
    var getCleanId = function () {
        return $routeParams.OID.substring(0, 2)
    };
```

Change the substring starting position to 1 to remove the prepended colon.

```
    var getCleanId = function () {
        return $routeParams.OID.substring(1, 2)
    };
```

That in turn should fix the issue with not getting a single record out of the web api.  The web api is trying to find a matching function signature in the controller on the web server. The only parameter can't convert to an integer, so it uses the Get() instead of the Get(int Oid).

Comment: The substring correction did fix the issue of prepanded colon, but, for some reason, my WebAPI is still not catching the request for a single id. I will post a separate question and will show my service there.